# How to disable Rhythmbox cover-art?

Tags: rhythmbox

How can I disable the cover-art (Thumbnail that appears in left bottom corner) in Rhythmbox music player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Rhythmbox menu, go to Edit>Plugins and deselect the plugin 'Cover Art.'